# Call to undefined function Laravel\Horizon\Console\pcntl_async_signals() (Laravel Horizon)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-horizon

I have installed laravel horizon using xampp having apache server. Here i need to use queue with redis so i have checked and installed wsl along with redis and run redis from wsl platform

insttalled Predis
and configure it accroiding to laravel guideline
[Laravel Horizon Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVuwZ.png)

when i run php artisan horizon getting the below error
Call to undefined function Laravel\Horizon\Console\pcntl_async_signals()

at vendor\laravel\horizon\src\Console\HorizonCommand.php:48
44▕         ProvisioningPlan::get(MasterSupervisor::name())->deploy($environment);
45▕
46▕         $this->info('Horizon started successfully.');
47▕
➜  48▕         pcntl_async_signals(true);
49▕
50▕         pcntl_signal(SIGINT, function () use ($master) {
51▕             $this->line('Shutting down...');
52▕

Comment: I have running all these in windows platform

Answer (score 0):

The [`pcntl_async_signals()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-async-signals.php) function is part of the [PCNTL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcntl.php) extension, which is not supported on Windows (as mentioned [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pcntl.php)):

> Note: This extension is not available on Windows platforms.